# How to use ng-model with generated tag directive to make binding work?

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating directive that makes tag dynamically depending on what type comes in.
But in this case I can't make `ng-model` work.

1) HTML:  `ng-repeat` repeat `custom-tag` and bind the `data`  (custom-tag could be `input` or `select`)

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in head">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" ng-if="key === item.name">
    <label>{{item.title}}</label>

    <custom-tag type="item.type" ng-model="data[key]"></custom-tag>

  </div>
</div>
{{data}}  // {"name":"0","number":"0","contact":"0","type":"0","id":8}
```

And this is my directive code:
This custom directive creates a `custom tag`, for example it's `'input'`, then I add an attribute `ng-model` but where to get the reference to the model I can't find. I've tried a lot of different ways.
And at the end I replace the `custom tag` with new created `input` tag

```js
 .directive('customTag', function($compile, $parse) {
 
   return {
     scope: {
       type: "="
     },
     require: '^ngModel',
     restrict: 'E',
     replace: true,
     link: function($scope, el, attr, ngModel) {

       var input = angular.element('<input/>');
           input.attr('ng-model', 'what/s here is going to be???')

       var linkFn = $compile(input);
       var content = linkFn($scope);
       el.replaceWith(content);

     }
   }
 })
```

What should I pass in the ng-model value to make it works?

It's work without isolate scope, but I need it to receive the type of element.

Sorry for my english and difficult explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass ngModel as additional binding:

```
.directive('customTag', function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel',
            type: "@"
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
            var input = angular.element('<input type="text" ng-model="model" />');
            var linkFn = $compile(input);
            var content = linkFn($scope);
            el.replaceWith(content);
        }
    }
});
```

and make sure you interpolate type, you don't need two-way binding here:

```
<custom-tag type="{{item.type}}" ng-model="data[key]"></custom-tag>
```

Comment: I've already done in another way. But your version is more simple and useful :)  Thanks a lot!